# How Can I Persist a Change Directory Outside of a Shell Script In Factor?

Tags: shell, factor-lang

I have the following factor code in a file:

```
IN: set-work-dir
USING: shell ;
CONSTANT: work-dir "/code" ! I also tried "c:/code" and "c:\\code"--same error
work-dir cd
```

When I attempt to run the script from factor I get this error:

```
C:\>/usr/bin/factor/factor /usr/bin/factor/work/set-work-dir.factor
Generic word absolute-path does not define a method for the fixnum class.
Dispatching on object: 47
(U) Quotation: [ c-to-factor => ]
    Word: c-to-factor
(U) Quotation: [ [ (get-catchstack) push ] dip call => (get-catchstack) pop* ]
(O) Word: command-line-startup
(O) Word: run-script
(O) Word: set-current-directory
(O) Method: M\ object absolute-path
(O) Word: no-method
(O) Method: M\ object throw
(U) Quotation: [
        OBJ-CURRENT-THREAD special-object error-thread set-global
        current-continuation => error-continuation set-global
        [ original-error set-global ] [ rethrow ] bi
    ]
```

I can get this to run if instead of `USING: shell ;` I have `USING: io.files.private` but the directory change isn't preserved outside of the running of the script.  I'm assuming using shell will cause the directory change to persist--which I realize may be a bad assumption. How can I write a script to change the directory and have the directory change persist outside of the script?

Windows 7 (*Yes, I know the dir separator on Windows is usually `\` and I tried '\' too.  But `/` actually works on Windows too.  Besides the path works when I use io.files.private).*

Factor 0.98 x86.64 (1788, heads/master-e187d63d3c, Tue Oct 18 02:14:22 2016)
[Microsoft Visual C++ 190023506] on windows

Comment: This is by design of the underlying OS, not a shortcoming of Factor. Child processes can't change the parent-process' CWD, not in Windows, not in Linux, and probably most OSs out there. There are probably some hacks that could work, but the best bet would be to call your Factor program from a batch script, return the directory on exit and have the script change the WD. In Windows I think .bat or .cmd files by default run in the same shell. For Linux (and I think PowerShell) it's the reverse, you have to specify you want the same shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cd` work exists in two vocabs. Which one `cd` will call depends on what you are `USING:`. If `shell` then `shell:cd` is called if `io.files.private` then `io.files.private:cd` is called. You can of course use the fully qualified name too.

Though the `io.files.private:cd` word shouldn't be used by user code because the vocab's name ends with `.private` which indicates that the word isn't part of the public interface. Instead use `set-current-directory`:

```
IN: scratchpad "/tmp" set-current-directory
IN: scratchpad "." absolute-path .
"/tmp"
```

The change will not persist after the Factor process terminates.

Comment: Yeah I suspect the Factor process terminating is the salient detail here.  But thanks anyway.